# Find all values of k such that the matrices are not row-equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:

Find all values of k such that the matrices

$A =  \left[
      \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & k + 1\\
        -1 & 3k -2\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$
and  $B =  \left[
      \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & 2\\
        3& 4\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$
are not row - equivalent.

What I know and my work:

Def: Two matrices are row - equivalent if one can be converted into the other using elementary row operations.

If they are able to be converted into each other then that means that they should have the same RRE form right? Therefore I should be trying to compare their RREs.

FOR B:

$B =  \left[
      \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & 2\\
        3& 4\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$

R2 = R2-3R1

$B =  \left[
      \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & 2\\
        0& -2\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$

R2 = -2R2

$B =  \left[
      \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & 2\\
        0& 1\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$

R1 = R1 - 2R2

$B =  \left[
      \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & 0\\
        0& 1\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$

FOR A:

$A =  \left[
      \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & k + 1\\
        -1 & 3k -2\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$

R2 = R2 + R1

$A =  \left[
      \begin{array}{cc}
        1 & k + 1\\
        0 & 4k -1\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$

This gives me k + 1 = 0, and 4k-1 = 1

Where do I go on from here? Or is this way completely wrong?

Comment: Are you getting unique k from the equation??? reduced echelon form is unique. not the Echelon form.  you are wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what elementary operations I need to do to get k+1 to go to 0 to get the RRE of A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemmas:

$1.)$ Invertible matrices are row equivalent to one another.

Proof: I think you got this one.

$2.)$ If an invertible matrix $C$ is row equivalent to an arbitrary matrix $D$, then $D$ is also invertible.

Proof: If $C$ ~ $D$, there exists elementary matrices $E_1, ..., E_n$ such that $$C E_1 ... E_n = D$$
Multiplying both sides by $E_n^{-1} ... E_1^{-1} C^{-1}$, we get that 
$$I = D (E_n^{-1} ... E_1^{-1} C^{-1}) $$
so  $(E_n^{-1} ... E_1^{-1} C^{-1}) = D^{-1}$

Your matrix $B$ is invertible since you can reduce it to the identity. In order to guarantee $A$ and $B$ are not row equivalent, we need that $A$ is not invertible.  By your calculation, this is the case if $4k- 1 = 0$ and so

$k= 1/4$

Comment: I apologize, while your proof makes perfect sense, I don't think I'm allowed to use determinants yet as it hasn't been taught. I was looking for help using the row echelon method to find the value for k.

Comment: The determinants were just to make things faster for me.  I actually didn't look at your attempt, and you already did most of the work.  I edited my answer accordingly.